# Close localhost tab after SSO authentication is successful for WPF application using MSAL.NET and Microsoft graph API

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal

I am able to perform the SSO authentication using MSAL.NET and Microsoft Graph API for my WPF application, It opens a browser tab as I have configured a Redirect URI on https://portal.azure.com/  as http://localhost while registering the application. I want to close the localhost tab automatically after SSO authentication is done.

I have tried the below piece of code :

```
   private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Acquire Access Token from AAD for Proxy Application
            _app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(ClientId)         
            .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")
            .WithAuthority(Authority)
            .Build();

            AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
            var accounts = await _app.GetAccountsAsync();
            IAccount account = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

            IEnumerable<string> scopes = new string[] { "User.Read", "openid", };

            try
            {               
                authResult = await _app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, account).ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
            {
                authResult = await _app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).WithUseEmbeddedWebView(false).ExecuteAsync();
                                   .ExecuteAsync();

            }           

            BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider accessTokenProvider = new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(new TokenProvider(authResult.AccessToken));
            GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(accessTokenProvider);
            User result = await graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync();
            GroupCollectionResponse g = await graphServiceClient.Groups.GetAsync();            
            DisplayBasicTokenInfo(authResult);
            DisplayGroupInformation(g);        

        }
```

Thank you..!!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you can not close a browser windows from the context outside the browser, You will need a browser extension for this. See: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aws-vpn-companion/lmffeiofldbdfahndommhemembdepbbc

Comment: Thanks @H.D.  for the suggestion, I was wondering if this can be done Programmatically, becasue this solution will not be accepted. Becasue in such case we have to ask clients to install that extension, and many will not agree for that.